# A Binary choice between using an abstract factory or partial classes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design

I am building a CRUD application with Entity Framework Model First approach. my application is structured in a way that the UI LAYER and the DAL both depend on the Domain Layer, and the domain layer doesn't depend on anything. the Domain layer exposes repository and domain object interfaces only. the repositories are implemented in the DAL and provided to the domain layer through dependency injection. as all repositories, my repositories expose functions like getCustomer, deleteCustomer, etc. but since those functions are implemented in the DAL, the DAL has to be able to create objects adhering to the interfaces in the Domain layer. now my binary choice is how should i let it do that: should i use abstract factories and inject them into the DAL or extend the definition of the partial generated entities and make them implement the interfaces exposed by the domain layer ?

Comment: Are you expecting somebody to swap out your DAL at some point in the future? Why the DI? Seems to me your are overcomplicating the solution.

Comment: @Heather, no over-complication actually. just designing the right way. DI is about following good principles after all before using any tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the Domain layer exposes repository and domain object interfaces only.

In this type or architecture ([hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture)), domain objects shouldn't have interfaces, only the repositories. Instead, have the DAL create (reconstitute) domain objects directly. There is no benefit gained in abstracting domain objects into interfaces, only needless complexities, such as factories.

Also, as pointed out by Heather, abstracting the repository is often a needless complexity as well. Making a repository abstraction which is truly portable across implementations is almost always futile. The central benefit of the repository abstraction, in my opinion, is that of encapsulation which can be attained without interfaces - just reference the implementing class directly.

Comment: What about testing? When I design a repository I'm always starting with the interface when a repository is required. I implement the repos much later in the project, after the domain objects are defined. The DAL implementation is among that last things I do.

Comment: To be honest, what you describe is my default approach. However, this can also be done by having your repository class be essentially a stub. Another way is to mock the repository object with a mocking framework. A repository interface can be good to have from an organizational perspective because it defines a contract for the repository. But I sometimes think that creating an interface just for testing is needless.

Comment: i must say that i agree with most of what you say except the repository part. so i approve the answer.